# Check if key is present in another array then take value

Tags: php

I am trying to check if month is present in another array, if yes take value from that array.

Months array

```
$months = array('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12');
```

Data array

```
$data = array("01"=>5,"02"=>2, "03"=>6.2, "11"=>10);
```

My solution

```
$newArray = array();
    foreach($months as $mon){

        foreach($data as $key => $value){

            if(isset($data[$mon])){ 
               $newArray[$mon] = $value;
            }
            else{
                $newArray[$mon] = '0';
            }

        }
    }
```

solution print:

```
"response": {
        "10": "0",
        "11": 10,
        "12": "0",
        "01": 10,
        "02": 10,
        "03": 10,
        "04": "0",
        "05": "0",
        "06": "0",
        "07": "0",
        "08": "0",
        "09": "0"
    },
```

A could be seen in response, value 10 is assigned to all keys. It should be assigned only to key 11, other keys should have different values as in data array."01"=>5,"02"=>2, "03"=>6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the buggy part :

Consider the current `$mon` is `01` and the `$key` `$value` pair is `"11"=>10`

```
if(isset($data[$mon])){        // $data[$mon] is set (this is $data["01"])
    $newArray[$mon] = $value;  //$value = 10 actually. It sets the wrong value to $newArray["01"]
```

You don't need that inner loop, since you can check `$data[$mon]` and use that instead of `$value`

```
$months = array('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12');
$data = array("01"=>5,"02"=>2, "03"=>6.2, "11"=>10);

$newArray = array();
foreach($months as $mon)
{
    if(isset($data[$mon])){ 
       $newArray[$mon] = $data[$mon];
    }
    else{
        $newArray[$mon] = '0';
    }
} 

var_dump($newArray);
```

**Output**

```
array (size=12)
  '01' => int 5
  '02' => int 2
  '03' => float 6.2
  '04' => string '0' (length=1)
  '05' => string '0' (length=1)
  '06' => string '0' (length=1)
  '07' => string '0' (length=1)
  '08' => string '0' (length=1)
  '09' => string '0' (length=1)
  10 => string '0' (length=1)
  11 => int 10
  12 => string '0' (length=1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Cid, exactly what I needed. I saw my mistakes now

Comment: Check others answers too, Second2None one is pretty nice

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop through the data array you just need to check if its set in the $data array:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($months as $mon){
   $newArray[$mon] = (isset($data[$mon]) ? $data[$mon] : '0'); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Second2None, works but it displays all data from data array

Comment: When I `var_dump($newArray);` I get the desired results :) I  just double checked.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want, you could make use of [`array_reduce`](https://3v4l.org/cXY5Z):

```
$result = array_reduce($months, function ($result, $month) use ($data) {
  $result[$month] = $data[$month] ?? 0;
  return $result;
}, []);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/WCIId

Comment: Thanks Jeto, but it doesnt print months in key

Comment: @Marko Sorry you're right, I fixed my answer. Gives you a nice and short alternative solution if that can help.